# Compiler error while defining array using typeof and decltype

Tags: c++, typeof, decltype

A)This works:

```
int main() {
    int * a = new int[5];
    delete[] a;
    return 0;
}
```

B)This errors out:

```
int main() {
    int * a = new typeof(*a)[5];
    delete[] a;
    return 0;
}
```

with error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript

C)This works:

```
int main() {
    int * a = new typeof(a)[5];
    delete[] a;
    return 0;
}
```

I can't understand why B fails because after expansion the statement should look like this:

```
int *a = new int[5];
```

because `typeof(*a)` is int.

Here's the experiment with decltype:

D) This doesn't work:

```
int main() {
    int * a = new decltype(a)[5];
    delete[] a;
    return 0;
}
```

with error: cannot convert 'int**' to 'int*' in initialization. This is expected given that decltype(a) is int* so it translates to `int *a = new int*[5];` which is incorrect.

E) But this doesn't work:

```
int main() {
    int * a = new decltype(*a)[5];
    delete[] a;
    return 0;
}
```

with error: new cannot be applied to a reference type

So be it a GCC extension or a standard C++11 feature, both don't appear to be working as per my expectations in all cases.

Comment: There is no `typeof` in c++. If you use compiler extensions - which you apparently do - then state which compiler you're asking about.

Comment: I get `error: expected type-specifier before ‘typeof’` - did you mean to write `decltype`?

Comment: @TobySpeight It's a gcc extension.

Comment: @molbdnilo - ah, so `-std=gnu++11` instead of `-std=c++11`; thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> or a standard C++11 feature, both don't appear to be working as per my expectations in all cases.

Then you have wrong expectations - at least in the case of `decltype`. I don't know how the gcc's `typeof`  works, so I can't answer to why B) works but C) doesn't but D) and E) behave according to the standard.

D) The expression given to `decltype` in this example is `a`. `a` is name of a variable. In other words it is an id-expression. In the case of an id-expression, `decltype` resolves to the type of the entity. The type of `a` is `int*`. Therefore `new decltype(a)[5];` constructs an array of `int*`. Because the type of `a` isn't `int**`, it cannot point to an array of `int*`.

E) The expression given to `decltype` in this example is `*a`. The type (`T`) of the expression is `int`. But `*a` isn't a name of a variable. It isn't an id-expression like `a` is. The value category of `*a` is lvalue. In case of an lvalue-expression, `decltype` resolves to `T&` where `T` is the type of the expression. Therefore, `decltype(*a)` is `int&`. Arrays of references are not allowed, therefore `new decltype(*a)[5]` is not allowed.

Here is the quote from the standard (draft):

§ 7.1.6.2 [dcl.type.simple]

> 4. For an expression
>      e
>      , the type denoted by
>      decltype(e)
>      is defined as follows:
>
> —
>    if
>   e
>   is an unparenthesized
>   id-expression
>   or an unparenthesized class member access (
>   5.2.5
>   ),
>   decltype(e)
>   is the type of the entity named by
>   e
>   . If there is no such entity, or if
>   e
>   names a set of overloaded func-
>   tions, the program is ill-formed;
>
> —
>    otherwise, if
>   e
>   is an xvalue,
>   decltype(e)
>   is
>   T&&
>   , where
>   T
>   is the type of
>   e
>   ;
>
> —
>    otherwise, if
>   e
>   is an lvalue,
>   decltype(e)
>   is
>   T&
>   , where
>   T
>   is the type of
>   e
>   ;
>
> —
>    otherwise,
>   decltype(e)
>   is the type of
>   e

This would be correct:

```
int * a = new std::remove_pointer<decltype(a)>::type[5];
```

and also this:

```
int * a = new std::remove_reference<decltype(*a)>::type[5];
```

Of course, both of those are quite pointlessly complicated. If your objective is to avoid repeating the type, then `decltype` is not the tool you should be looking for. The tool that fits your needs is `auto`:

```
auto a = new int[5];
```

Answer (score 1):

*a is a pointer to int so cant call typeof on it this way

```
int *a = new int[5];
```

works because you are showing to integer and declarating the new array of size 5 on the place where a shows

maybe you wanted :

```
typeof(new typeof(int *)[5])a;
```

instead

```
 int * a = new typeof(*a)[5];
```

Comment: `a` is a pointer to `int`. `*a` is an `int`. `typeof(*x)` is even one of [gcc's examples](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html).

Comment: *a is not a pointer to int. *a is what a points to, an int. So why doesn't it work ? I essentially want to eliminate any data type mention in the definition statement and want to use the existing variable itself, hence your suggestion `typeof(new typeof(int *)[5])a;` though correct, isn't what I am looking for.

Comment: int *s;
 typeof (*s)m[5];
 s=m;